# Differences between test spy implementations

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, testing

I am having some trouble defining which kind of test doubles these two classes are.
They both contain (basic) behaviour.

Their difference is that the first in a real context would not run, while the second would (it'd be basically a does-nothing class, but it'd work! The second would crash).

They both seem like [Test Spies](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mocks,%20Fakes,%20Stubs%20and%20Dummies.html) to me. They both provide a way to get whether the `Run()` method was called or not. (that is these classes' reason of being!).

I can't use the second one as it is in all the contexts, as I can't also use just the first one in all contexts.

I could refactor both of them into one, but maybe that'd turn things less clear when reading the code.

```
class FilterTestSpy : IFilter {
    private bool hasBeenRan = false;

    ...

    public bool HasBeenRan { get { return hasBeenRan; } }

    public void Run() {
        hasBeenRan = true;
    }
}

class FilterTestSpy2: IFilter {
    private bool hasBeenRan = false;

    ...

    public bool HasBeenRan { get { return hasBeenRan; } }

    public void Run() {
        ...some logic...
        hasBeenRan = true;
    }
}
```

I know there are mocking frameworks, blablabla, that is not what I am asking about here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a strategy to delegate to in the `Run()` method?  That way you will be able to have just one spy class, with a single responsibility, i.e, tell whether the method was called. So, for different contexts, you can inject different strategies.

Comment: Yes, I could (in fact that's what I ended up doing my code). But the question still remains, what name to give to each running instance, so I can better describe what that running implementation is going to do.